# Strange behavior of Nested while loop while iterating over a text file

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am new to java. I am trying to iterate over a couple of `.txt` files to compare one line of the file to every line of the second file. these are my two files: `listread.txt` and `csvread.txt`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
try {
        BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/data/csvread.txt"));
        BufferedReader listReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/data/list.txt"));
        String csvItem, listItem;
        int count =0;
        while((csvItem = csvReader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println("before second loop:"+csvItem);
            while ((listItem = listReader.readLine())!= null) {
                System.out.println("list Item: "+listItem.toLowerCase().split("¬")[1]);
                System.out.println("csv Item: "+csvItem.toLowerCase());
                if(listItem.toLowerCase().split("¬")[1].contains(csvItem.toLowerCase())){
                        count++;
                }
             }
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I run this, only the first line in the `csvread.txt` (which is stored in the variable `csvItem`) is being compared to each of all the lines in `listread.txt`. Here is an example output:

```
before second loop:Record Category   
list item: provisions
csv Item: record category    
list item: request category
csv Item: record category    
list item: elevator
csv Item: record category    
list item: assessment
csv Item: record category    
list item: associates
csv Item: record category    
list item: score
csv Item: record category    
list item: attachments
csv Item: record category
```

It only iterates over all the lines of `list.txt` file with the first line of the `csvread.txt` file. Doesn't move on to the second line in the `csvread.txt`, and the program ends throwing an error in the last:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at test.main(test.java:52)
```

Which refers to the line `System.out.println("list item: "+listItem.toLowerCase().split("¬")[1]);`. This statement has nothing to do with the iterations I guess. Not sure why this error is thrown..

However, When I comment out the second for loop, it runs fine iterating over all the lines in the `csvread.txt` file. Here's is a sample output with just the first while loop and the second loop commented out:

```
before second loop:Record Category   
before second loop:Type 
before second loop:Name
before second loop:State
before second loop:Number
before second loop:ID (Self)
before second loop:Parent
before second loop:Title
```

This issue is occurring only when there is a nested loop. when there is a single loop, there is no problem at all. can somebody shed some light on this strange behavior? Also how do I overcome it?

**EDIT:**
I've added an `if` condition to check if the line contains the `¬` befor I split the line on that character:

```
 if(listItem.contains("¬")){
        System.out.println("list item: "+listItem.toLowerCase().split("¬")[1]);
        System.out.println("csv Item: "+csvItem.toLowerCase());
        if(listItem.toLowerCase().split("¬")[1].contains(csvItem.toLowerCase())){
                count++;
         }
   }
```

No I don't get the exception anymore. However, The behavior is still strange. Here's the output after adding the `if`:

```
before second loop:Record Category   
    list item: provisions
    csv Item: record category    
    list item: request category
    csv Item: record category    
    list item: elevator
    csv Item: record category    
    list item: assessment
    csv Item: record category    
    list item: associates
    csv Item: record category    
    list item: score
    csv Item: record category    
    list item: attachments
    csv Item: record category
    before second loop:Type 
    before second loop:Name
    before second loop:State
    before second loop:Number
    before second loop:ID (Self)
    before second loop:Parent
    before second loop:Title
```

The other elements are now being iterated over in the `csvread.txt` but the comparison with the lines in `listread.txt` is not hapeening except for the first element.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You have a line that doesn't have `¬` so it doesn't get split and the array has no element with index `1` . Start by fixing this problem.

Comment: Also, on the first iteration the inner loop reads to the end of the list.txt file so `listReader` is pointing to the end of the file.  On the next outer loop iteration, since `listReader` is already pointing to the end of the file the inner loop is not executed.

Comment: So, that's how it works? How do I bring it to the beginning again? Is there a better way to iterate? @AndrewS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanded from my comment about `listReader` pointing to the end of the file after the first iteration. `BufferedReader` doesn't provide a mechanism to move the file pointer so a simple approach would be to move the creation of `listReader` to inside the outer loop:

```
try {
    BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/data/csvread.txt"));
    // BufferedReader listReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/data/list.txt"));
    String csvItem, listItem;
    int count =0;
    while((csvItem = csvReader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println("before second loop:"+csvItem);
        BufferedReader listReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/data/list.txt"));
        while ((listItem = listReader.readLine())!= null) {
            System.out.println("list Item: "+listItem.toLowerCase().split("¬")[1]);
            System.out.println("csv Item: "+csvItem.toLowerCase());
            if(listItem.toLowerCase().split("¬")[1].contains(csvItem.toLowerCase())){
                    count++;
            }
         }
    }

}catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

so each iteration will have a new `listReader` which starts at the top of the file.

But that might be too much I/O.  If the size of list.txt isn't too big, then perhaps read it once, parse it, and store in a `Set<String>` for later comparison:

```
    try (BufferedReader listReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/data/list.txt"));
            BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/data/csvread.txt"))) {
        String listItem = null;
        Set<String> listItems = new HashSet<>();
        while ((listItem = listReader.readLine()) != null) {
            listItems.add(listItem.toLowerCase().split("¬")[1]);
        }

        String csvItem;
        int count = 0;
        while ((csvItem = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("before second loop:" + csvItem);

            for (String item : listItems) {
                System.out.println("list Item: " + item);
                System.out.println("csv Item: " + csvItem.toLowerCase());
                if (item.contains(csvItem.toLowerCase())) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also moved to try-with-resources to make sure `csvReader` and `listReader` are properly closed.

Comment: I haven't yet tried the first approach. But I'm certain that the second way works. Thanks for the great answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use nested loops, the inner loops get executed fully. Then the execution control comes out of the inner loop and starts the next iteration of the outer loop. Hence, if you want to compare the content of the two files line-by-line, you should not have any inner loop. Below is the sample code that you may try to do in this case. Though, I have not tested it.

```
try {
    BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/data/csvread.txt"));
    BufferedReader listReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/data/list.txt"));
    String csvItem, listItem;
    int count =0;
    while((csvItem = csvReader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println("before second loop:"+csvItem);
        listItem = listReader.readLine();
        if (listItem != null){
            if(listItem.toLowerCase().split("¬")[1].contains(csvItem.toLowerCase())){
                    count++;
            }
        }else{
            //The listItem has no more lines to compare, so ending the process.
            break;
        }
    }

}catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Note: The above answer was given with a belief that the requirement was to compare the contents of two files line-by-line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this approach does not allow me to compare a single line of the 1st file with all the lines of the 2nd. It just compares one to one.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought one-to-one comparison was the intention here.

Answer (score 0):

Your access to

```
listItem.toLowerCase().split("¬")[1]
```

is critical, since you always expect that all lines have your "¬". If this is not the case your split will not return a array and you access the returend array at position [1] which fails and returns the IndexOutOfBounds....